# random number gen, loop and store

Tags: c#

How can I implement this so it is always ten numbers in length and how would I store n and r, loop 10 times, and store each loop aswell?

loop the random generator 10x to create 2x10 multiple 10 digit numbers.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            F();
            F();
        }

        static Random _r = new Random();
        static void F()
        {

            int n = _r.Next();
            int r = _r.Next();

            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: loop over what? Question is extremely unclear.

Comment: sorry loop the random generator need to loop it 10x to create 2x10 multiple 10 digit numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may be what you're looking for?

Though I'm not keen on the naming conventions, I'm not sure what these apply to, so can't exactly name them relevantly myself...

```
static int[] randomNumberArray0 = new int[10];
static int[] randomNumberArray1 = new int[10];
static Random random = new Random();

static void PopulateRandomNumberArrays()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        randomNumberArray0[i] = random.Next();
        randomNumberArray1[i] = random.Next();
    }
}
```

***Update:***

To execute this method then further output the values at a later time, try this:

```
static void PrintRandomNumberArrayValues(int[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", array[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

static void Main()
{
    PopulateRandomNumberArrays();

    PrintRandomNumberArrayValues(randomNumberArray0);
    PrintRandomNumberArrayValues(randomNumberArray1);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output would look something like this:

```
2044334973
153458690
1271210885
734397658
746062572
162210281
1091625245
123317926
410432738
989880682

866647035
481104609
834599031
1153970253
94252627
1041485031
1934449666
414036889
1886559958
2083967380
```

***Further update:***

For the generated values to be constrained to 10 digits in length, it means the minimum generated value must be larger than `999999999` and, since an `int` has a max value of `2,147,483,647`, smaller or equal to that, so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    randomNumberArray0[i] = random.Next(1000000000, int.MaxValue);
    randomNumberArray1[i] = random.Next(1000000000, int.MaxValue);
}
```

I have a feeling this still may not satisfy your needs though, as what I see coming next is that the numbers should be able to be represented as `0000000001`, for instance - let's see.

***Yet another update:***

As I thought, the value of numbers should not be constrained to our specified range, but rather only the output formatted appropriately; thus generation reverts to my original suggestion and printing is altered as so:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D10}", array[i]);
```

Comment: My mistake - missing `static` modifiers: updated the answer to reflect.

Comment: how do I get the console app to stay open and output the two arrays?

Comment: Updated my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: im getting two arrays with numbers now thanks but the groups of numbers are less than 10 need each random number generated to be exactly 10

Comment: yup the out is what im looking for but i need every set of numbers to be exactly ten digits long

Comment: I see, this really wasn't clear in your original question - please see my last update.

Comment: not sure if its the number generator but im getting alot of the lines starting with 1, infact every instance is 8/10 start with 1

Comment: With values only ranging between `1000000000` and `2147483647`, probability would suggest so.

Comment: is there a way to increase the int value to 9999999999?

Comment: That's a formatting issue, remove the min and max value constraints of `random.Next` and within `PrintRandomNumberArrayValues` use this: `Console.WriteLine("{0:D10}", array[i]);`

Comment: still only getting 0, 1 and 2 as the start digits no way to make it a Big Int?

Comment: Not if you wish to continue using `Random`, no.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use a list of tuples to store and return your results:

```
static List<Tuple<int,int>> F()
{
    var results = new List<Tuple<int,int>> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        results.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(_r.Next(), _r.Next()));
    }
    return results;
}
```